# Courier MYSQL_QUOTA_FIELD isn't working

Tags: imap, courier, ubuntu-12.04

In /etc/courier/authmysqlrc, I have

```
MYSQL_QUOTA_FIELD CONCAT(quota, 'S')
```

But connecting to the account via RoundCube or Thunderbird with the Display Quota plugin shows an unlimited/unknown quota.  In the quota field, I have entered 1000000, and this table/row is otherwise working perfectly for authentication.

I enabled mysql logging and checked the query log for the query that courier is executing for auth.  When I execute it myself it works fine and correctly returns "1000000s" for the quota.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found that I can add a maildirsize folder to the root of my mail account, with contents of "1000000S" to set a quota.  This document (http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/README.maildirquota.html) explains in detail.  However, if someone still knows a way to set this through MySQL, I'll award you the answer.

Comment: sorry, I meant a maildirsize file, not folder